# Range of object Global failed

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to reference a row in my program to change it's interior color, I can do the entire row, but it looks sloppy when there is only one column of data (the entire row is highlighted grey to the end of the page even though there is one column of data). So I attempted to just use a range of end of row, but I am getting the range of object failed error.

```
ws1.Rows(i).Copy
ws4.Cells(z, 1).PasteSpecial
'ws4.Rows(z).Interior.Color = rgbLightGrey -----Comment-----
ws4.Range(z, Range(z).End(xlToRight)).Interior.Color = rgbLightGrey
```

The commented row is what I am using now, but I'd like to implement the End of row method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `z` appears to be an Integer (or Long), not a range reference.

Use:

```
ws4.Range(ws4.Cells(z, 1), ws4.Cells(z, 1).End(xlToRight)).Interior.Color = rgbLightGrey
```

Edit:  I just noticed that you say that you only have one column of data.  If so the above code won't work, because `.End(xlToRight)` will find the first non-empty cell to the right of cell `ws4.Cells(z, 1)`, stopping at the end of the row.

If you are just trying to colour the single cell, use:

```
ws4.Cells(z, 1).Interior.Color = rgbLightGrey
```

Next edit, based on comments:

To select the range between column A and the last non-empty cell in the row, use:

```
ws4.Range(ws4.Cells(z, 1), ws4.Cells(z, ws4.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Interior.Color = rgbLightGrey
```

Comment: Thank you, it won't error out on me anymore. However, I will sometimes have rows with empty columns of data that need to have the interior color as well. So, I need something to look after end of row, because after the end of row blank space(s), there will be more data, most likely, and it all needs to be highlighted as one big row. Not sure how to approach this. By the way, there shouldn't be more than 4 columns in one row that won't have data. So the biggest gap between data would be 4 columns.

Comment: @rdan1 - Have edited the answer to cater for setting colour of a single cell, or for setting the colour for the entire row up to the last non-blank cell.

Comment: ok, I have rows that have a blank space in the last used column of data, so I removed the .End() portion and just used the columnscount I set earlier in the program and everything works great now :D.  Thank you for teaching me that I needed to reference a range and not an integer.

Comment: Ahh - the dreaded explicit space!  If you have one of those there isn't much to do (easily) other than what you just did.  For the sake of accuracy, I will modify my answer again to refer to `last non-empty cell` instead of `last non-blank cell`.